# WSL-2 `code` command installs vscode instead of using local windows install

Tags: wsl-2

I have a local vscode installed for windows.
Afterwards I setup wsl-2 and use it as my shell.
When I tried to open a file with code using the `code filename` command, it installed vscode anew instead of using the local windows install.

```
Installing VS Code Server for x64 (054a9295330880ed74ceaedda236253b4f39a335)
```

**Is there a way to point wsl to use the windows install when triggering it via the code command?**

I don't specifically mind using either or, but settings/extensions etc. for one are not used by the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By checking with *Git Bash* where the location of code is when triggering it (`type -a code`) and comparing it to the ubuntu wsl shell, I came to the conclusion, that it is actually the same install that is being triggered, . I will have to check why some extensions do not seem to "carry over" though.

The code that is being triggered is a script, that behaves differently when being triggered from within `WSL`.

Answer (score 0):

How about an alias?

```sh
# Set alias
alias code2='/mnt/c/Users/Username/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft\ VS\ Code/bin/code'

# Open a file now
code2 file.txt
```

Comment: Hey DieOde. Thanks for trying to help. But as I stated in the answer below, it is actually the same install, the "Installing" part I was seeing for just for WSL support I think. When starting code from within WSL there seems to be some special behavior.

Comment: Specifically it seems to start it as a remote editing session, with WSL:Ubuntu being the remote.